# How to solve node on linux server 502 error?

Tags: node.js, express

I deploy node app on server, but it gives me error 502. I don't know what happened with this. Please check my code below and guide me where I am wrong.

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var staffMail = require("./routes/staffMail");
// var usersRouter = require("./routes/Level");

var app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", test);
app.use("/test", staffMail);
// app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.listen(5000, 'localhost');
module.exports = app;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: app.listen(3000,function(err){
if (err){
console.log(err);
}
console.log('server started on port 3000'
})
change this and check if it works?

Comment: I have a question too, are you using any proxy?and i can see module.exports, so which means you are trying to export this app file, where are you importing this?
I do it like this when i need to export my app file 
import app from "./mainApp.mjs";


const port = 3000||process.env.PORT;






app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is up and running on port ", port);
});

Comment: @JatinMehrotra i am using express builder and by default express make /bin/www file

Comment: Check my solution if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename app.js to anything else except server.js (ie main.js) and reference that in bin/www by pointing to it in the /bin/www file: var app = require('../app'); to var app = require('../main');

or if it doesn't work,set this in bin/www.

```
 app.set('port', 8081||process.env.PORT);

Reason node app.js is not opening ports hence 502 error which means bad gateway.
```